# C: Reading double from stdin using read system call

Tags: c, double, system-calls

I am asking how can I read a double, int or any other type from `stdin` using the `read` system call.

What I've done so far:

```
long val ;
ssize_t r;
r = read(STDIN_FILENO,&val,sizeof(long));
printf("%ld\n",val);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Mind if you post a small example with what you tried earlier (and what went wrong)? The problem could have been something relatively small (at least compared to starting from scratch).

Comment: I do know scanf ,fscanf ...and other many standard ways to read a double from stdin ,
but in this case , i want to read a double from stdin with a system call using read.
the rest of the code is :

`if(r == -1){
perror("read");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}`

example of use 
i enter 451245 , the programm will just take care about the 4 first bytes (size of long) , and then will ignore the rest and will display  , a value wich is different from what was typed!

Comment: What value would you want or expect reading 451245 as a long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not being clear whether you want to read (a) the ASCII representation of a long, double, int or whatever (i.e. the string "0.12345", or (b) the binary representation of that value.

If you want to do (a), you need to use `fscanf`. See the above answer.

If you want to do (b), your code looks right to me. What is the 'bad result' you are having? Did you check for `r<0`, then look at `errno` or use `perror()`.

I suspect the problem is you wanted to do (a), but have coded for (b).

Answer (score 0):

Use `stdio` and `scanf`

See http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

This will be easier to use that a raw read

**EDIT**

Read what you are initially expecting then try the others until you get a hit.

Better still redesign the user interface so that this problem does not arise

Comment: I think `stdin` might prove a little more useful in this case

Comment: @barakmanos - Surely you just try them one after another until you get a hit or you have an idea of that is expected.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to say, but in any case, you'd still need to use `stdin` as a FILE pointer passed to `fscanf` if you were to read data from `stdin` (i.e., from the keyboard).

Comment: `stdio` is the library. `scanf` reads from `stdin`. Just a little shortcut (please read the manual page)

Comment: So is he asking in the question how to read a value from the keyboard without knowing the actual input type in advance?

Comment: @barakmanos - I assumed that he is reading an ASCII representation of something (int, double etc) as it is from STDIN. Without any other knowledge I do not understand why the person is in the predicament.

Comment: So what's wrong with simply reading it as a string using `fgets` or `fscanf`, and then parsing it with `scanf("%lf"...)` if it contains a '.' or with `scanf("%lld"...)` otherwise?

Comment: `scanf` reads from STDIN - i.e. the same as `fscant(STDIN, ...`. The data is held in a buffer BTW

Comment: Sorry, I meant `sscanf`